# Is it possible to apply a print style rule to an element on screen?

Tags: html, css

Say I wanted to show a print preview, would it be possible to have an iframe or a div element use print media query instead of screen? something akin to this:

```
<iframe media='print'></iframe>
```

I already have a CSS file with print media, the issue is just triggering that selector outside of using print preview.

Comment: media attribute is not avalaible for the iframe element. if you link a CSS file with media="print", it will be for print only. idem via @media print . You need to link the CSS straight to the document . but you are not telling how you fill the src attribute of your iframe.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus does that mean that if I add a link with attr media, the linked stylesheet would have the selector applied automatically?

Comment: No, I don't think so. But it's a nice idea.

Comment: How do you send content into that Iframe ? so we can see how you put it to show and probably advise you how to link that content to the CSS file specified for print. if you print rules stands inside an `@media print { selector{/*style*/}}`  it will remain for print only.

Comment: You're asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). Instead of asking about a proposed (and possibly flawed) solution, ask about your _problem_.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can modify your print page css as below

first you need to create a file as name is `yourcssfile.css` then add it in your `html` file like this,

```
<link href="yourcssfile.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

inside

```
 @media only screen and (max-width : 640px) { 
 /* All your print styles go here */
 #header, #footer, #nav { display: none !important; } 
}
```

Comment: media="print" @media print is only for print, not for a preview in the window ;) , remove the print keyword for screen  so it can be triggered at screen .then the question will become how can i load only that one file/stylesheet ;)

Comment: it is the question that is bad actually, do not worry ;)